# Kafka log & index files are modified when broker is stopped

Tags: apache-kafka

We are currently running with 2 Kafka clusters, version 0.9.0.0, and in both we've noticed the following behavior: when a broker is stopped (kafka-server-stop.sh), all the log & index files of all of its topics are being modified (we simply see that the modification time of all the files is updated).
The problem with this is that it damages the retention policies once the broker is started again (as far as I understand, the retention policy relies on the file's modification time). Thus, if, for example, my retention policy is set for 24 hours and the broker is restarted every 23 hours, old logs will never be deleted.

Did anyone encounter this behavior? Any idea why this happens and how to fix this?

Thanks